# Is there a way to autoplay a YouTube video when it has scrolled into viewport and pause when scrolled out?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, viewport, autoplay

I am using ACF flexible fields and I have added a field for the Youtube link in each block. When I scroll to each block, I would like the Youtube iframe to start playing automatically (so when it has reached the viewport). When I scroll out of this block I would then like it to pause, and when it's reached the next block it will play that, etc. Please could someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that YouTube doesn't allow to autoplay the videos without a user interaction... you can read the [iframe api reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

I tried with this JavaScript function:

```
function isInViewport(element) {
  const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

This function returns 'true' if the passed element is in the viewport and false if not in.

Then I use another function called in each addEventListener for 'scroll' and 'resize' events:

```
function checkScroll() {
  // Get the video element
  var video = document.getElementById('player');

  if (isInViewport(video) == true) {
    playVideo();
  } else {
    pauseVideo();
  }
};
```

But like I say at the beginning, this only works if user initiates the player by an interaction.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, however sorry I'm trying to apply this to Youtube iframes specifically (using the youtube api) as opposed to HTML5 videos, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am adding a window.addEventListener() on onPlayerReady(), however it is not working. For example, I am using this as a reference: https://codepen.io/discreteprojects/pen/xbORdg, however I can't seem to get it to work with multiple videos on the page.

Comment: Thanks Jesus. I think the youtube api about not autoplaying is relating to mobile only. I think I understand your code above, thank you, but I'm struggling to get this code to work with multiple youtube videos. Here is my Codepen if you wanted to try this out from your side: https://codepen.io/ECUSER/pen/YzEjVWq. I imagine it's got something to do with the duplicated ID's? Thank you!